# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined

Tags: angular, typeerror, google-places-api

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined

This error keeps popping up when I run my Angular Application. It says something is wrong with my search.component.ts file at line 25. Here is my search component

```
    /// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss'],
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  autocomplete: any;
  @ViewChild('search')
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
  public searchControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone, 
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();

    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
        let autocomplete = new window['google'].maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: [],
        componentRestrictions: {'country': 'US'}
      });
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
          this.searchControl.reset();
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `new window['google'].maps.places` this part is `undefined` or `null`. Hence the error.

Comment: @Nikhil How do I fix that?

Comment: @Rfoxes: Does your application compile fine even with the error?

Comment: @Michael D Yes it does

Comment: @Rfoxes: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Check you have activated and imported `&libraries=places` in your script embed link

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ config.MAPS_API_KEY }}&libraries=places&callback=initMap&v=weekly" async></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**&libraries=places**

need to add to your script tag.

I had same problem when I was trying autocomplete feature of GoogleMap according to this example :

[example](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/google-maps-simple-store-locator#2)

Then I changed my script tag like below that fixed the problem.

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application compiles fine with the error, then it's a TS Lint error. It's because the Lint can't find the properties accessed using the dot `.` operator. You could work around it using the bracket notation `[]` instead. Try the following

```js
let autocomplete = new window['google']['maps']['places']['Autocomplete'](this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
  types: ["address"]
});
```

More about property accessors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but this did not work. I was looking online, and I found something called ngx-google-places-autocomplete that I could import. Do you know the difference between that and @types/googlemaps? Or is that just a wrong approach?

Comment: I can't comment on the other module as I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={YOUR-API}&libraries=places" async></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).